# Loop add .last class to last item in loop

Tags: php, wordpress

Im using wordpress and using the following to get the last 3 most recent posts:

```
    <?php query_posts('showposts='.$latest_num.'&cat=-'.$featured_cat.','.$latest_ignore.''); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <li>
        <div class="imgholder">
            <a href="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/slide1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[featured]" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail',true) ?>" width="275" height="145" alt="Post Image" class="postimg-s" />
            </a>
        </div>
        <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
        <p><?php the_content('Read more...'); ?></p>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

What I want to do is add a class named `'last'` to the `<li>` element on the 3rd interation through the loop.

Anyone got any ideas how I could add this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Li should be li

```
<li <?php $iCounterLi++; ($iCounterLi==3)?'class="last"':''; ?>>
```

Don't forgot to initialize the $iCounterLi before the loop

Comment: Consider `$iCounterLi == $latest_num` in order to avoid the need to change the number of items several places. (My bet is that all is forgotten about the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Unnamed_numerical_constants) `3` whenever someone wishes to list five items instead :) )

Answer (score 4):

Setup a counter outside your while loop

```
$count = 1;
```

Check the modulus of that counter and output the class if required

```
<li <?php if(!$count % 3) echo 'class="last"; ?>>
```

Increment your counter before closing the loop:

```
    $count++;
}
```

Or, applied to your code:

```
<?php 
    $count = 1;
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
?>
<li <?php if(!$count % 3) echo 'class="last"; ?>>
    <div class="imgholder">
        <a href="/wp-content/themes/twentyten/images/slide1.jpg" data-gal="prettyPhoto[featured]" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumbnail',true) ?>" width="275" height="145" alt="Post Image" class="postimg-s" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
    <p><?php the_content('Read more...'); ?></p>
</li>
<?php
    $count++; 
    endwhile; 
?>
```

The counter-intuitive look of the modulus condition is that whenever the counter is divisible  by exactly 3 it will return 0.

Answer (score 3):

Replace the line

```
<li>
```

with

```
<li <?php print have_posts() ? '' : ' class="last"' ?>>
```

> The `have_posts()` simply calls into
>   `$wp_query->have_posts()` which checks a
>   loop counter to see if there are any
>   posts left in the post array ([source](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop))